# Proper way to create a set method of a Class

Tags: php, class, singleton

I'm having trouble passing a unit test. The problem is that the set method creates the index, but I don't know how to return the true value. I'm not really understanding how to properly create a set method for this particular unit test.

```
<?php

class Config
{
private  static $instance;
public static $config;


private static function load($data) {
    $data = include('data.php');
    static::$config = $data;
    return static::$config;
}

// constructor
protected function _construct(){}

private  function _clone(){}

private function _wakeup() {}

// function to get the instance config
public static function singleton(){
    /**
     *  Returns single instance of this class
     *
     */
    if(Config::$instance === null) {
        Config::$instance = new Config();
    }

    return Config::$instance;
}

public static function set ($setData, $flag = false) {
   $instance = Config::$instance;

   $instance->$setData = $setData;

    if($instance->$setData) {
        return $flag = true;
    }else {
        return $flag = false;
    }

   //return $instance->$setData = $setData;
}
}
```

And this the test that I'm trying to pass

```
<?php

assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1) and assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL, 1);

$config = Config::singleton();
assert($config === Config::singleton());

$config->set('foo', true);
assert($config['foo'] === true);


print "All Tests Passed\n";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to do `$instance->$setData = $flag;`, not `$instance->setData = $setData`. Also, in `private static function load($data) { $data = include('data.php');` the `$data` argument is ignored - is that intentional? And, the constructor should be named `__construct` (with 2 underscores), as do the magic methods. Have a look at [__set()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set).

Comment: Hi Kenney you are right the $data parameter is not being used so I removed it. The data.php file is a config file that returns an array of key values. But when I run the test it says "Cannot use object of type Config as array". Do you know why that is?

Comment: Yes, that would be the `assert( $config['foo'] === true )`. I'll post an example.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot modify the test, to fix the `Cannot use object of type Config as array`, your `Config` object must be made to act like an array. It needs 2 changes:

- Extend [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)
- Call the `ArrayObject` constructor to configure it properly:

```
class Config extends ArrayObject {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct( array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS );
  }
  ...
}
```

Without the `ARRAY_AS_PROPS` option, you would get an error `Undefined index: foo`.

**Alternative**

This is typically done by implementing `__set`, `__get`, `__isset`. and `__unset`.

The idea is that you access the configuration elements *as if* they were fields, as in:

```
$config->foo = 'bar'
```

In this case, if the field `foo` doesn't exist, PHP will call `$config->__set( 'foo', 'bar' )`. Similarly if you read the field, `__get( 'foo' )` will be called.

See [PHP Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) for details.

Here's the updated test:

```
<?php
require_once 'Config.php';

assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1) and assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL, 1);

$config = Config::singleton();
assert($config === Config::singleton());

$config->foo = true;
assert($config->foo === true);

print "All Tests Passed\n";
```

And here's `Config` class, with a few modifications:

- Instead of storing the configuration data `$config` in a `public static` field, it's stored as a `private` field.
- The static `Config::set()` method delegates to the `$instance`.

```
class Config
{
  private  static $instance;
  private $config;

  private static function load() {
      $data = include('data.php');
      static::$config = $data;
      return static::$config;
  }

  // constructor
  protected function __construct(){}

  /**
   *  Returns single instance of this class
   */
  public static function singleton(){
    return self::$instance === null
      ? self::$instance = new Config()
      : self::$instance;
  }

  public static function set($field, $value) {
    return Config::$instance->$field = $value;
  }

  public function __set($field, $value ) {
    $this->config[$field] = $value;
  }

  public function __get($field) {
    return $this->config[$field];
  }

  public function __isset($field) {
    return isset( $this->config[$field] );
  }

  public function __unset($field) {
    unset( $this->config[$field] );
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Kenney, I thank you for the input. The thing is that this is a test written by my supervisor. I can't change the test. So is there any way to create the set method to pass the first test?

Comment: I see. Well, normally you cannot use an object as an array, but there is [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), and easier, [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php). Though it's somewhat bad practice to `->set()` (object method) and `['....']` (array access) on the same variable. I don't know if extending `ArrayObject` is something that 'fits' with your assignment?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, but is it really what you need? If the test cannot be modified, we're going to have to find another solution.

Comment: No it's not what I needed, but I know that your answer could help someone with a similar situation that can modify the test. When I try to extend ArrayObject I can because I'm implementing Iterator which is a requirement of the test. I can implement ArrayAccess but I'm a like lost on how to use it.

Comment: Updated - the test passes, and only your Config class is modified. I left in the original answer because it is the 'proper' (or most common) way to have a generic setter. Hope this solves it for you!

Comment: Is it possible to extends to ArrayObject and implement Iterator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102790/discussion-between-eric-evans-and-kenney).